# Where is the My Music folder on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, music

I've read that I should store songs in the "My Music" folder. Where is that folder located?

All my music software was removed when tech support wiped the hard disk clean. When I play a song I saved to the desktop, it only plays the first 5 seconds and is thus unusable. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-download the file again, it might have got corrupted as it was downloading.

You can save your music wherever you like. The "My Music" folder is a regular folder, just like any other; music in there will play no different than in other locations, unless you have software that expects music to be in that folder. You should see a shortcut to "My Music" in your Start Menu.

<sub>I would sue someone who destroyed my data while "fixing" my PC. It's *not* ok to screw up like that. People should admit if they are clueless, instead of taking money and apologizing afterwards. I'm baffled that people do this and get away with it.</sub>

Comment: My Music is a regular folder, yes, but its location is specially recorded in the registry. Many music apps look up this location and use it as a default.

Comment: Good point. It won't fix this issue though- it finds the file and still can't play it properly.

Comment: Based on the headline and the only actual question asked, it seems he is only asking where My Music is. His wiped drive and corrupt file aren't relevant.

Comment: Perhaps you are not familiar with the term "XY problem". You need to read up on it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. The OP's REAL question was buried in the middle of his poorly phrased question: "Yesterday, I downloaded a song of 2 minutes and 43 seconds of music. I saved it to the desktop. It only plays 5 seconds and is therefore unusable." Anyone can see that he doesn't care two hoots about some folder he only just discovered existed- he wants to play the music he paid for. There's no need to overcomplicate this.

Comment: It remains to be seen what his "real" question was. I see no harm in answering _every_ question he asked, whether he did so implicitly or explicitly. It is not overcomplicating anything.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command shell window and enter

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "My Music"
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Music"
```

This should give you an idea of where the actual folder is.

Comment: This whole "My Music" folder thing is a total red herring.

The real problem is the user can't play a song he paid for and downloaded- and it's not going to matter where he puts this corrupted file, he still needs to download it again intact.

Besides, someone who doesn't know where the My Music folder resides and needs to rely on a (very incompetent) tech to help with basic computer problems is *not* the sort of person who will have a CLUE what to do with your registry queries. In theory you did answer his question- but in reality it is not helpful in the *slightest*.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting my answer as being some kind of rebuttal or attempt to be superior to yours, which it is not. It is just addressing an aspect of his question that you left unanswered. In other words, between the two of us, we both answered both of his questions - the one he actually asked, and the one he didn't ask, so there shouldn't be any problem _in theory_ — certainly no reason to downvote or be so defensive. Also, where are you getting that he paid for his music?